# Analytic and numerical integration of the rocket equation yield different results

Tags: classical-mechanics, simulations, rocket-science

**Background**

The mass of a rocket as a function of time is:
$$ m = m_0 - \dot m t$$
Where $m_0 $ is the initial mass of the rocket and $\dot m$ is the mass flow rate. At a certain time all the fuel has been used, so from that time onwards $m = m_f$, the mass of the rocket without fuel.

The speed is then defined by the following equation, where $V_e$ is the exhaust velocity and $g$ is constant gravity.
$$v = V_e log({m_o \over m_o - \dot mt}) - gt$$

To obtain position let $\dot m$ be constant, the equation can be written as

$$v = V_e log({m_o \over m_o -  kt}) - gt$$ 
Integration of that expression lets to the following, which corresponds with the expression contained in Orbital Mechanics by Curtis.

$$h = \frac{V_e}{\dot m}[(m_0 - \dot m t)log({m_o - \dot mt\over m_o })+ \dot mt] - \frac{1}{2}g t^2 $$

**Question**

However, the plot of $h$ (**Red**) is different for what I get for evaluating $v$ and then doing a numerical integration (**Blue**). Both plots are similar until the time where the fuel runs out, then the difference is easily visible.

The analytic plot sounds more reasonable to me since a rocket needs multiple stages to achieve a high altitude, but the numerical method is harder to get wrong and is necessary to consider other factors such as drag. Can someone point me in the right direction? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code I used in MATLAB. The values used are an approximation to the Saturn V, just considering one stage.

```
t = 0:1:1600;

%Constants
mass_inital = 2970.000;
mass_final = 731.000;
flow = 13.120;
exhaust = 2.500;
g = 9.81/1000;

mass = mass_inital - flow .* t;
mass(mass< mass_final) = mass_final;

v = exhaust .* log(mass_inital./mass) - (g .* t);

c = cumtrapz(v);
h = (exhaust ./ flow).* (mass.*log(mass./ mass_inital)+ flow .* t) - (0.5 .*g .*(t.*t));

%Plots
plot(t,c);
hold on
plot(t,h);
ylim([0 max(c)]);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about debugging code and not physics.

Comment: "the numerical method is harder to get wrong" - that is one of the funnier things I've read in a while! People get numerical methods wrong all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fourth equation (for *h*) in the *background* section indeed seems to be the analytical integral of *v*. However, this is only true for the limited duration until fuel is exhausted.

From there on, the equation for *v* should be modified and this would modify the integral for *h*.

Most likely the last term in the square brackets for *h* ($\dot{m}t$) is incorrect when fuel is exhausted and is imposing extra height.

Comment: Yes! Adding the following equations after the time the fuel runs out (tbo) yielded the curve obtained in numerical integration. Thanks;                                              v = (vbo - g.*(t-tbo)); 
h = (hbo + vbo.*(t-tbo)- (0.5 .* g .*power((t-tbo),2)));